# Stored Procedure with partial commits (called from Java) - PostgreSQL 11

Tags: java, spring, postgresql

I have a SP in PostgreSQL 11 whose structure is something like this below.

So the idea of this SP is that we don't lose all the updates/inserts (done in the SP) if some statement fails. We only lose the updates/inserts which happened after the last commit.

OK, so I call this SP from DBeaver and I get the expected behavior, the changes done before the first 2 commits remain in the DB, i.e. get persisted to the DB.

Now I am trying to call the same SP from Java code using **Spring 4.3.21**, 
**JDBC driver postgresql-42.2.5.jar**, and **Hibernate version 5**.

(1) The Java method which calls this SP is configured as Spring transactional like this `<prop key="process*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-Exception</prop>`.

OK... but then from the Java code I am getting a different behavior (not the one from DBeaver). From Java I get now this error: `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid transaction termination` and this error comes from the 1st commit.
No matter what I do I always get this.

So it seems like from the SP code I cannot commit the transaction which Spring started?! Why is it not allowing me to commit? What am I doing wrong?

What is the right way to call the SP from Java/Spring in the way I want it?!

(2) Also... if I try to call the SP from Java/Spring from a non-transactional method (non-transactional in the Spring sense), then I get an error from Spring itself: transaction required.

So...it seems there is no way for me to call this SP from Java/Spring and have these first two commits succeed.

What is the right way?

I've been struggling with all this for the past 2-3 days now.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS yb.test123;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE yb.test123()

LANGUAGE plpgsql

AS $procedure$ 

DECLARE
    cnt int;
    c int;
BEGIN

    --- do some inserts/updates - they all succeed

COMMIT; -- commit #1 


    --- do some inserts/updates - they all succeed


COMMIT; -- commit #2 

    --- do some inserts/updates - 1 of these fails

COMMIT; -- commit #3

END
$procedure$;
```

Comment: Trace the SQL and see what statements are actually executed. If there is a `SELECT` in the call stack, that would explain the error.

Comment: If you are using spring framework you cannot use `commit` inside your procedure. Spring is the `Boss` here to manage transactions. If you use commit inside procedure with spring, then spring does not know anything about it. You need to rewrite your procedure to java code with proper bussines behaviour or split big procedure to smaller ones and invoke them from spring.

Comment: @PawełGłowacz This is really stupid... But yes, you seem to be right. I found a workaround anyway a few months ago. Thanks.